# javascript included files are gone after AJAX reload

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page in which I refresh a `DIV` by a `JQUERY` Ajax call, but I then lose al the `javascript` code that I included in the "head" page. Do I need to include them twice? Looks to me that's not good for the performance, because you have to load the `javascript` again while it is on the client page already. How to include the files so that they are also available after Ajax refresh

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $("#prijzen_huidige_jaar").submit(function(event) {    
    /* stop form from submitting normally */    
    event.preventDefault();      
    $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"prijzen_huidige_jaar_test.php",
    cache: false,                   
    data: $("#prijzen_huidige_jaar").serialize(),
    success:function(data){
        $("#test").replaceWith(data);
    }       
});
});
});
```

include in the main page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://localhost/include_bestanden/javascript/prijzen.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post all of your code please? Both the JavaScript and HTML, that way we'll be better able to help you.

Comment: Strange! love to see your jquery.

Comment: added the jquery Ajax call, alle the code is a bit to much....

Comment: Please edit your question and post the html code there, not in the comments.

Comment: Please also post a bare-bone HTML structure that shows the position of the element `#test` and a sample of the data returned by the ajax call.

Comment: The page: https://www.huurhulp.nl/wijzigen/wijzigen.php?wijzigen_adv=14&code=523a98367bfb05765fb86a2535966aad

Comment: Click on prijzen 2012 and do a submit, this tab will be submitted and reload the form by AJAX

Comment: Can you confirm the `#test` div is supposed to contain the (long) form `#prijzen_huidige_jaar`? This what is replaced?

Comment: The Javascript is to show/hide questions div's. If youre not posted the form you can see it working

Comment: show - hide the questions. If you clicked ja on a question, the div has to show up and it does not anymore. Before the submit it did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `click` in your JS, you should use `on` with class identifiers, as this will apply to elements added later via AJAX.

So instead of:

```
$("input[name$='vraag_afwijkende_prijzen']").click(function(){          
    if($(this).val() == 1){
        $("#instructie_afw_prijzen_tekst").html(vraag4_ja);
        $("#afwijkende_prijzen_vak").show('slow');
        $("#afwijkend_1").show('slow');
    }
    //etc
```

Try something like:

```
$(document).on("click", ".vragen-radio", function() {
     if ($(this).attr("name") == 'vraag_afwijkende_prijzen' && $(this).val() == 1) {
        $("#instructie_afw_prijzen_tekst").html(vraag4_ja);
        $("#afwijkende_prijzen_vak").show('slow');
        $("#afwijkend_1").show('slow');
     }
     //etc
```

You can read about it in this question: [Why use jQuery on() instead of click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click)

Comment: Yeah!!! this works! I do have some other strange behavior, if i hit submit for a second time, than he loads an completely other page. Before the adjustment it was also there, you know why?

Comment: Maybe because the Jquery function as mentioned in the question has the same problem? Is not included in the DIV after AJAX? Look like it, i tested it and the whole function isn't executed after submit for a second time...

Comment: Yep! did the job at the same way!

Comment: ehhh, next problem, my datepickers is not working anymore after a submit. See the tab "basisgegevens" question 2 (answer "ja")