# Remove affecting Jquery script?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a script that makes a table responsive (footable). This works great for my needs but I use some ajax to bring in some more table rows, but the script doesn't affect these new rows.

I have tried to reinitiate the script after my ajax has completed but it doesn't work.

My question is, can I remove the affecting jquery so that I can reapply it after the data has been loaded?

My jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
table();

$('#moreevent').click(function(){
var last = $('#the-event tr').length;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.php",
    data: { levent: last }
}).done(function( data ) {
    $('#the-event').append(data);
    cardbox();
    table();
});

return false;
});

});

function cardbox(){
jQuery('.e-info-more-cont').hide();
jQuery('.e-info-more').mouseover(function(){
    jQuery(this).css({"z-index":"1001"});
    jQuery(this).nextAll(".e-info-more-cont").show();
}).mouseout(function(){
    jQuery(this).nextAll(".e-info-more-cont").hide();
    jQuery(this).css({"z-index":""});
});
}

function table(){

jQuery('.footable').footable();
}
```

Comment: known issue: https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable/issues/32

Comment: ah, thats the problem. I don't suppose you found a way around it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.click()` which is deprecated and does not handle dynamically added items. Depending on your jQuery version, either use `.on()` (recommended), or `.live()`

**Edit:** As suggested, `.click()` is not deprecated, however it is still suggested to use `.on()` wherever possible.

Comment: `click()` is certainly not deprecated

Comment: .click() is not deprecated. However, .live() is.

Comment: From what I remember, it was suggested to avoid it. In newer versions, it is now aliased to `.on()` since people kept on using it. Amended answer with your feedback.

Comment: Eli Sand wrote up a good summary of on() vs click() vs. live() here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10082242/605643

Comment: so if I were to change to use on, would I still need to remove the script or could I just call the function again?

Comment: in theory, you just need to change `.click()` to `.on()` and it should work.

Comment: nope afraid not, same issue, just need to find away to remove the script first