# jQuery for more or less with pagination works only once

Tags: jquery, primefaces, datalist, jquery-pagination

I am using jQuery for my application using primefaces with datalist. this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
            var showChar = 100;
            var ellipsestext = "...";
            var moretext = "Daha Fazla";
            var lesstext = "Daha Az";
            $('.more').each(function() {
                var content = $(this).html();

                if(content.length > showChar) {

                    var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
                    var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

                    var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span><a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';

                    $(this).html(html);
                }


            $(".morelink").click(function(){
                if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
                    $(this).removeClass("less");
                    $(this).html(moretext);
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("less");
                    $(this).html(lesstext);
                }
                $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
                $(this).prev().toggle();
                return false;
            });
            });
        });
```

I actually get it from this website : http://www.midnight-coding.com/2012/09/jquery-implementing-show-more-show-less.html?showComment=1370956365671#c4153997055911566116

but the problem I get is when I go for another page using datalist pagination, the script does not work. in other words, the script only works once.

can anybody help me about this? thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi Zeynep. When I created the DEMO on the blog I was working on a secluded piece of code. I never worked with primefaces before (or JSF in general). I would wonder if there is some DOM change done by the JSF files which cause the element with the `.morelink` to be removed/re-added. Does the show more/less click always work when you are not paging and only starts breaking when you page? This could possible be an issue whereby the click events need to be re-bound every-time the grid is paged.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing your click handler with .on:

This:

```
$('.morelink').click(function () {
```

Becomes something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.morelink', function () {
```

Take a look at the following question [Why use jQuery on() instead of click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click) for a good explanation but essentially you are binding your click event to that instance of the .morelink container. If you overwrite that  in jQuery you lose the event.

Comment: i have writed replacing '$('.morelink').click(function () {' with this '$('body').on('click', '.morelink', function () {' but the result is the same unfortunately. thank u, any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you put together a fiddle @ jsfiddle.net that more clearly demonstrates the problem you are having?

Comment: Thanks @Zeynep_Eyyuboglu, but I am not seeing any pagination or anything in the results panel.

Comment: yes brett i think that unfortunately this site does not support primefaces :( and i could not find any useful thing on the internet. problem is still.