# Cant change display value with jquery on click

Tags: jquery, css

Im trying to make simple button to show and hide menu when screen is smaller than 35em. But the issue is that my jQuery click event doesnt change display value for my list items.

CSS:

```
div{
  list-style:none;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
ul li{
  display:inline-block;
}
#menuToggle {
  display:none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 35em) {
  #menuToggle {
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
  } 
  ul li{
    display:none;
  }
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#menuToggle').click(function(){
  $('ul li').css('display','block');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/bLamG/

How can I establish that?

Comment: It does work: See fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/bLamG/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work, but you have no closing `);` so your code is throwing a syntax error. Try this:

```
$('#menuToggle').click(function () {
    $('ul li').css('display', 'block');
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bLamG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing `);`

You should also use 'on' method instead.

```
$('#menuToggle').on('click', function () {
     $('ul li').css('display', 'block');
});
```

Comment: Why on()? My #menuToggle is on the page at first when page is generated. Isnt click() just a shorthand for that?

Comment: Just incase you would want to create menu items dynamically. This explains it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click

Comment: @ChrisTill the `on()` function you've used does not have a delegate parameter, so will not work for 'creating menu items dynamically' anyway.