# Attaching unique click events to each Repeated instance of an Array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, jquery-events

Here is an example of three forms with the same repeated instance and no unique identifier:

```
<form action="/haters"><input type="submit" value="stop hatin"></form>
<form action="/haters"><input type="submit" value="stop hatin"></form>
<form action="/haters"><input type="submit" value="stop hatin"></form>
```

How can I attach a different console.log or any message triggered by a click to each of these buttons?

I am targeting these buttons so far with a jQuery Dom selector `$("form[action='/haters']")`

I posted on codepen also: http://codepen.io/marc313/pen/uphiv

Comment: you want each click event do different things?

Comment: when I target these elements in the DOM it is an array of each instance. Think click the first button, console.log('click 1st button'); click the second button, console.log('click 2nd button'); and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could bind to each button individually, as in @Deryck's answer, often times such practice leads to duplicate code. Its likely your actual use case isn't to log 3 different things to the console when 3 buttons are clicked.

Particularly if these 3 buttons do similar actions or if they act on the same set of data, its often much more clean to do something like this:

## jQuery

```
$('document').on('click', 'form[action=haters]', function() {
    /* This event will fire for any form with action="haters"
     * that is on your page. */

    var $clickedElement = $(this); // jQuery collection of the clicked element

   /* If you slightly modify your markup, as in the example below, you can
    * quickly uniquely identify each button, and act accordingly, like so: */

    var id = $clickedElement.attr('data-id');

    if(id === 1) {
        stuffForFirstButton();
    } else if(id === 2) {
        stuffForSecondButton();
    } else if(id === 3) {
        stuffForThirdButton();
    }
});
```

## Markup

```
<form action="/haters"><input type="submit" value="stop hatin" data-id="1"></form>
<form action="/haters"><input type="submit" value="stop hatin" data-id="2"></form>
<form action="/haters"><input type="submit" value="stop hatin" data-id="3"></form>
```

**Reference**

- [On calling .on() for event binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click)

Answer (score 1):

**Each item in a set will have an `index` number and you can use that to identify them.**

### jQuery:

```
$('input[type=submit]').eq(0).on('click', function() {
    console.log('This is unique to the FIRST submit button');
});
$('input[type=submit]').eq(1).on('click', function() {
    console.log('This is unique to the SECOND submit button');
});    
$('input[type=submit]').eq(2).on('click', function() {
    console.log('This is unique to the THIRD submit button');
});
```

[The `.eq()` method](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) means "equals" and refers to the index number for the selector you chose in `$('input[type=submit'])`.

If you want to do that **systemically**, you can put that into a `for()` or `while()` loop.  Of course, you would replace `eq(0)` with whatever number you want to use to identify the button (starting from 0 being the first element in the set, not greater than `$('input[type=submit]').length`).

Here's a fork of your [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fxJqd) to see it in action with `alert()`

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way for that is adding names to this inputs and later you can grab each input by a name and using click function for each.

```
<input type="submit" value="stop hatin" name="first">

$("#first").click(function() {
function
}
```