# How can i take all specific span and invoke click event based on id?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Currently i am doing as below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
debugger;
$('#Draft').live('click', function () {
alert("I am Draft Here");
});

$('#Live').live('click', function () {
alert("I am live Here");
});

$('#Completed').live('click', function () {
alert("I am completed Here");
});
});
</script>
```

I am fetching each element's id and based on that invoking alert on click event of that.

Is there any way in which i can fetch all span elements, say whose style attribute is like `style="color:`

Below are like my span elements on page

```
<span style="color:#F3660E;" id="Draft">Draft: (2138)</span>
```

I am new to jquery, please suggest on this

Comment: you can do this using `class name` instead of `style ="color:#color"`.

Comment: Add a common class then use it like http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/1ea99qsc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give them all a class, e.g.:

```
<span class="thingy" id="Draft">Draft: (2138)</span>
```

(You can remove the `id` unless you're going to use it for something.)

Then:

```
$(document.body).on("click", ".thingy", function() {
    // `this` will be the span element
});
```

Example:

```js
$(document.body).on("click", ".thingy", function() {
  $("<p>").html("You clicked " + this.id).appendTo(document.body);
});
```

```css
.thingy {
  color: #F3660E;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="thingy" id="Draft">Draft: (2138)</span>
  <span class="thingy" id="Live">Live: (1234)</span>
  <span class="thingy" id="Completed">Completed: (4321)</span>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

Note that in the above I used [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on), not [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live). `live` was deprecated several versions ago and removed a couple of versions back. `on` is how you do this with any recent version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a common class to all the elements.

```
<span class="myClass" id="Draft">Draft: (2138)</span>
```

Then you can bind event use class `.myClass`

```
$('.myClass').on('click', function () {
    //Here this refers to span, element which invoked the event
    alert("I am " + this.id + " Here"); 
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/satpalsingh/1ea99qsc/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use click. For a short description of difference between click and on look at answer in [Why use jQuery on() instead of click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click)

For your example I would probably just use //because it's shorter :)

```
$('.someClass').click(function(){
alert("I am someClass");
});
```