# how to add a CSS attribute just for specific time via JQuery (revert back to normal after 2 sec)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set a CSS attribute for a element *(div)* *just* for 2 sec. here is my try:

**html:**

```
<div class="div">foo</div>
<input class="btn" type="button" value="click" />
```

**jquery:**

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
   $(".div").css({"border": "1px solid #ccc"});
});
```

But the above code will be applied for ever, how can I limit it for a  specific period ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think using css class maybe the best solution just because i don't know the prev border style or the others css rules applied to the element:

css

```
.borderStyle{
    border: 1px solid #ccc!important;
}
```

js

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.div').addClass("borderStyle");
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.div').removeClass("borderStyle"); }, 2000);
});
```

toggle class version

```
$('.btn').click(function(){
    $('.div').toggleClass("borderStyle");
    setTimeout(function(){ $('.div').toggleClass("borderStyle"); }, 2000);
});
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gypfdpgm/)

don't know why the toggleclass don't work for you but lets keep it shown in my answer for future reviews

Comment: the class won't remove.

Answer (score 3):

I think you could use something like this :

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
    $(".div").css({"border": "1px solid #ccc"});
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".div").css({/* Your initial css */});
    }, 2000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty simple, add a `setTimeout()` and let that run after 2 seconds and let it remove the border.

```
$(".btn").on("click", function() {
    $('.foo').css('border', '1px solid #ccc');
    setTimeout( function() { 
        $('.foo').css('border', 'none');
    }, 2000);
});
```

**[Working JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/0h0shoas/1/)**

As you can see, I have replaced your `.click()` with `.on()`. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click) why it's better to use `.on()` and [here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) how you use it.

Answer (score 1):

After two seconds to remove css atribute:

```
$(".btn").click(function(e) {
   $(".div").css({"border": "1px solid #ccc"});
   setTimeout(function() { 
       $(".div").css({
           'border' : 'none',
           'width' : '30px',
           'top' : '10px',
           'left' : '30px',
           'bottom' : '10px',
           'right' : '30px'
       });
   }, 2000);
});
```

Comment: there is not just `border`, there is 6 attribute. I can not set them `none` again.

Comment: @Sajad here is solution with 6 random attributes, change them to 6 that suite you.

Comment: worked, +1 voteup for you. but I think there is a more optimized approach.

Comment: You can do it with class in css, so you will write less javascript, but more css.

Comment: yea, I want that way. and I did it, but I don't know why the class just `add` and don't `remove`