# why are the dynamically loaded events not working properly in my code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

guys i managed to load contents from database dynamically using ajax (JQUERY) but the problem is i'm not able to make them work properly, as i have jquery events to hide classes that are not hiding and links that wont do their normal behaviour when clicked. dont know where i'm going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

here is the jquery code that loads data dynamically:

```
$(".hidden_textarea").hide();
$(".hidden_edit_4_session").hide();
$(".hidden_edit_4_friend").hide(); 
//logic for infinite scroll

                var load=0;

     var sess_uname="<?php echo $session_uname;?>";
     var f_uname="<?php echo $f_uname;?>";
     var sess_count="<?php echo $total_sess_count;?>";
     var f_count="<?php echo $total_friend_count;?>";
     if(sess_uname==f_uname){
         $(window).scroll(function(){
             if($(window).scrollTop()==$(document).height()-$(window).height()){
             load++;

             if(load *2 >sess_count){
                 $(".message").text("no more posts to show");
             }else{
                 $.post("st&com.php", {load:load},function(data){
                  $("#status_area").append(data);

                 });
             }
             }
         });
     }
```

here is the entire php code that loads data dynamically using ajax:

```
<?php

include "includes/dbconfig.inc.php";
$status_replies="";
$status_list="";
$statusui_edit="";
$isowner="";
$is_friend="";
$statusdeletebutton='';     
$reply_delete_button="";
$load=  (int)($_POST['load'])*2;
function hashtags($dat) {
$regex="/#+([a-zA-z0-9._-]+)/";
$dat1=  preg_replace($regex, '<a href="hash_sys.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $dat);
return $dat1;

}
function taggingsys($dat) {
$regex="/@+([a-zA-z0-9!._-]+)/";

$dat1=  preg_replace($regex, '<a href="home.php?u=$1">$0</a>', $dat);
return $dat1;

}
$sess_id=(int)$_SESSION['id'];
$friends = array();
$stmt=  $conn->prepare("select friend_one, friend_two from friends where (friend_one=:session OR friend_two=:session) and accepted='1'");
$stmt->bindparam(":session",$_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();
$fetch=$stmt->fetchAll();
$count=count($fetch);


    if($count==0){
     $totalids=$project->totalUpdates1($sess_id,$load); 

 /*   foreach ($totalids as $v) {
        print_r($v); 
    $id=$v['user_id'];
    //fetch update_id from update table in db and inject it to the feed query.
    //$totalUpdates=$project->totalUpdates1($id);   
   */ 
    foreach ($totalids as $row1){

                $updateid=$row1['update_id'];

                $account_name=$row1['account_name'];
                $u_id=$row1['user_id_u'];
                $author=$row1['author'];
                $post_date=$row1['time'];
                $title= stripslashes($row1['title']);
                $data= stripslashes($row1['update_body']);
             $data1=  hashtags($data);
           //   $data1=  taggingsys($data0);
              $pic=$project->viewByUname($author);
              $uid=$pic['user_id'];
         $datemade = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($post_date));
           $avatar=$pic['avatar'];
          if ($avatar!=""){
          $feed_pic='user/'.$uid.'/'.$avatar;
      }  else {
          $feed_pic='img/avatardefault.png';
          }

                include 'ratings/vote_count.php';
             $like='<a  type="like" class="btn status_like_'.$updateid.' like" attr="'.$updateid.'">Like</a>('.$num_likes[0].')';
             $unlike='<a  type="unlike" class="btn status_unlike_'.$updateid.' unlike" attr="'.$updateid.'">Dislike</a>('.$num_unlikes[0].')';
$share_button="";
                 $hidden_text= '<textarea class="hidden_textarea hidden_value'.$updateid.'" type="hidden" disabled>'.$data1.'</textarea>';
                   $share_button="<a class='btn share_btn share_".$updateid."' title='".$title."' type='share' id='".$updateid."'>Share</a>";


                if ($author==$_SESSION['uname'] || $account_name==$_SESSION['uname']) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a  type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_status_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
                $edit_btn='<li>'
                        . '<a attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>';
                $statusui_edit="<div type='".$updateid."' class='hidden_edit_4_session session_editor".$updateid." jumbotron'>"
            . "<a type='".$updateid."' class='btn pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a>"
            . "<input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit title_s_".$updateid."' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title' >"
            . "<span>&nbsp;</span>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_edit_1' type='".$updateid."' rows='5' cols='50'  class='session_edit text_value_".$updateid."' wrap='hard' placeholder='whats up ".$session_uname."'>
             ".html_entity_decode($data1)."</textarea><br>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' value='".$updateid."' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div>" ;

                }else{
                    $statusdeletebutton="";
                    $edit_btn="<li class='posted'>You are not the owner of this Post</li>";
                    $statusui_edit="";
                }

       echo $statusui_edit.''. $hidden_text.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 class="pull-left title">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy posted" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                         .$edit_btn .' '. $statusdeletebutton .'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span style="font-size: 13.5px;" class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data1).'</span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'"><img src="'.$feed_pic.'" height="20px" width="20px"> '.$author.   '</a>   '.$datemade.'</small></b>'
                        . '<br><legend>'.$like.' | '.$unlike. ' | '.$share_button.'<h4><a id="'.$updateid.'" class="btn collap-btn">Comments</a></h4></legend>';

       ?>

    <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->

   <?php
// Fetch Comments of update
  echo '<div id="toggle'.$updateid.'" class="collapse">'; 
   $totalComments=$project->totalComments($_SESSION['uname'],$friend,$updateid);   
        foreach($totalComments as $row1){
             $status_reply_id=$row1['comment_id'];
                $reply_d=htmlentities($row1['comment_body']);
                $reply_data=  stripslashes($reply_d);
                $reply_osid=$row1['os_id'];
                $reply_date=$row1['time_c'];
                $reply_author=$row1['author_c'];
               $reply_data1=  hashtags($reply_data);
               // $reply_data1=  taggingsys($reply_data0);
                $datemade_r = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($reply_date));
                include 'ratings/vote_count4comments.php';
               $like_r='<a  type="like" class="btn status_liker_'.$status_reply_id.' like_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Like</a>('.$num_likes_r.')';
             $unlike_r='<a  type="unlike" class="btn status_unliker_'.$status_reply_id.' unlike_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Dislike</a>('.$num_unlikes_r.')';
      $pic=$project->viewByUname($reply_author);
              $uid=$pic['user_id'];

           $avatar=$pic['avatar'];
          if ($avatar!=""){
          $feed_r_pic='user/'.$uid.'/'.$avatar;
      }  else {
          $feed_r_pic='img/avatardefault.png';
          }


        if ($reply_author==$_SESSION['uname'] ) {
                   $reply_delete_button='<li><a type="'.$status_reply_id.'" class="btn delete_reply_btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_"'.$status_reply_id.'" title="Delete this comment"> Remove</a></span></li>';
               } else{
                   $reply_delete_button="";
               }
              echo '
                <div  class="replyboxes pull-left reply_' .$status_reply_id.'">'
                      . 'Reply by:- '
                      . '<a href="home.php?u='.$reply_author. '"><img src="'.$feed_r_pic.'" height="20px" width="20px">'.$reply_author.'</a>'
                      . '<span class="pull-right">'.$datemade_r 
                       . '<b class="dropdown">
                         <small><span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown"  >
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">'.$reply_delete_button
                      . '</ul></span>'
                      . '</small></b><br><legend>'.  html_entity_decode($reply_data1).'<br>'.$like_r.'|'.$unlike_r.'</legend></div>';


               } 
        echo '<textarea id="reply_textarea_'.$updateid.'"  class="status_reply_'.$updateid.' input-custom2" placeholder="comment\'s"></textarea>'
                            . '<button id="reply_butn_'.$updateid.'" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_butn reply_'.$updateid.'">Reply</button></div></div>';

        }
} //}
else{
  $friends = array();
$stmt=  $conn->prepare("select friend_one, friend_two from friends where (friend_one=:session OR friend_two=:session) and accepted='1'");
$stmt->bindparam(":session",$_SESSION['uname']);
$stmt->execute();

   foreach ($stmt->fetchAll() as $i=> $r ) {

    $r["friend_one"] == $_SESSION['uname'] ? $friends[]= $r["friend_two"] : $friends[] = $r["friend_one"]; 

    $friend=$friends[$i];

    $friend_count=count($friends);


     $totalids=$project->totalids($_SESSION['uname'],$friend);  

     foreach ($totalids as $v) {

    $id=$v['user_id'];

    //fetch user_id from update table in db and inject it to the feed query.
    $totalUpdates=$project->totalUpdates1($id,$load);   
    $total_sess_count=$project->totalupdatescount($id);

    foreach ($totalUpdates as $j=>$row1){

                $updateid=$row1['update_id'];

                $account_name=$row1['account_name'];
                $u_id=$row1['user_id_u'];
                $author=$row1['author'];
                $post_date=$row1['time'];
                $title= stripslashes($row1['title']);
                $data= stripslashes($row1['update_body']);
              $data1=  hashtags($data);
              //$data1=  taggingsys($data0);
              $pic=$project->viewByUname($author);
              $uid=$pic['user_id'];
         $datemade = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($post_date));
           $avatar=$pic['avatar'];
          if ($avatar!=""){
          $feed_pic='user/'.$uid.'/'.$avatar;
      }  else {
          $feed_pic='img/avatardefault.png';
          }
                include 'ratings/vote_count.php';
             $like='<a  type="like" class="btn status_like_'.$updateid.' like" attr="'.$updateid.'">Like</a>('.$num_likes[0].')';
             $unlike='<a  type="unlike" class="btn status_unlike_'.$updateid.' unlike" attr="'.$updateid.'">Dislike</a>('.$num_unlikes[0].')';
$share_button="";

                  $hidden_text= '<textarea class="hidden_textarea hidden_value'.$updateid.'" disabled>'.$data.'</textarea>';
                   $share_button="<a class='btn share_btn share_".$updateid."' title='".$title."' type='share' id='".$updateid."'>Share</a>";


                if ($author==$_SESSION['uname'] || $account_name==$_SESSION['uname']) {
                $statusdeletebutton='<li>'
                           . '<a type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn delete_4_session hidden_text_delete_'.$updateid.' glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_status_btn" title="Delete this status and its replies">Remove</a></li>';
                $edit_btn='<li>'
                        . '<a attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="btn edit_4_session hidden_text_edit glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" title="Edit this status" >Edit</a></li>';
                $statusui_edit="<div type='".$updateid."' class='hidden_edit_4_session session_editor".$updateid." jumbotron'>"
            . "<a type='".$updateid."' class='btn pull-right close_edit' title='Close without editing'>Close X</a>"
            . "<input type='text' class='form-control title_s_edit title_s_".$updateid."' name='status_title' value='".html_entity_decode($title)."' placeholder='Title' >"
            . "<span>&nbsp;</span>"
            . "<textarea id='wall_edit_1' type='".$updateid."' rows='5' cols='50'  class='session_edit text_value_".$updateid."' wrap='hard' placeholder='whats up ".$_SESSION['uname']."'>
             ".html_entity_decode($data1)."</textarea><br>"
            . "<button style='float:right;' value='".$updateid."' type='a' class='btn btn-warning btn btn-large btn-lg post-s-edit'>Update</button></div>" ;

                }else{
                    $statusdeletebutton="";
                    $edit_btn="<li class='posted'>You are not the owner of this Post</li>";
                    $statusui_edit="";
                }

       echo $statusui_edit.''. $hidden_text.'<div attr="'.$updateid.'" type="'.$updateid.'" class="statusboxes status_'.$updateid.'  jumbotron">'
                        . '<h3 class="pull-left title">'
                        . '<div id="'.$updateid.'" class="title_s_2copy posted" value="'.html_entity_decode($title).'">'.html_entity_decode($title).'</div></h3>'
                        . '<span class="pull-right">'
                        . '<div class="dropdown">'
                        . '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"  >'
                        . '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></button>'
                        . '<ul class="dropdown-menu">'
                         .$edit_btn .' '. $statusdeletebutton .'</ul></div></span><br><hr>'
                        . '<legend><span style="font-size: 13.5px;" class=" data_s_2copy" type="'.$updateid.'" >'
                        . html_entity_decode($data1).'</span></legend><b class="posted"><small>Posted by:-  <a href="home.php?u='.$author.'"><img src="'.$feed_pic.'" height="20px" width="20px"> '.$author.   '</a> on   '.$datemade.'</b>'
                        . '<br><legend>'.$like.' | '.$unlike. ' | '.$share_button.'</legend></small>';

       ?>
<h4><a id="<?php echo $updateid;?>" class="btn collap-btn">Comments</a></h4>
    <!-- Collapsible Element HTML -->
  <div id="toggle<?php echo $updateid;?>" class="collapse scroll-comments">

   <?php
// Fetch Comments of update
        $totalComments=$project->totalComments($_SESSION['uname'],$friend,$updateid);   
        foreach($totalComments as $row1){
             $status_reply_id=$row1['comment_id'];
                $reply_d=htmlentities($row1['comment_body']);
                $reply_data=  stripslashes($reply_d);
                $reply_osid=$row1['os_id'];
                $reply_date=$row1['time_c'];
                $reply_author=$row1['author_c'];
                $reply_data1=  hashtags($reply_data);
                //$reply_data1=  taggingsys($reply_data0);
                $datemade_r = strftime("%B %d", strtotime($reply_date));
                include 'ratings/vote_count4comments.php';
               $like_r='<a  type="like" class="btn status_liker_'.$status_reply_id.' like_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Like</a>('.$num_likes_r[0].')';
             $unlike_r='<a  type="unlike" class="btn status_unliker_'.$status_reply_id.' unlike_r" attr="'.$status_reply_id.'">Dislike</a>('.$num_unlikes_r[0].')';
      $pic=$project->viewByUname($reply_author);
              $uid=$pic['user_id'];

           $avatar=$pic['avatar'];
          if ($avatar!=""){
          $feed_r_pic='user/'.$uid.'/'.$avatar;
      }  else {
          $feed_r_pic='img/avatardefault.png';
          }

        if ($reply_author==$_SESSION['uname'] ) {
                   $reply_delete_button='<li><a type="'.$status_reply_id.'" class="btn delete_reply_btn glyphicon glyphicon-trash delete_reply_"'.$status_reply_id.'" title="Delete this comment"> Remove</a></span></li>';
               } else{
                   $reply_delete_button="";
               }
              echo '
                <div  class="replyboxes pull-left reply_' .$status_reply_id.'">'
                      . 'Reply by:- '
                      . '<a href="home.php?u='.$reply_author. '"><img src="'.$feed_r_pic.'" height="20px" width="20px"> '.$reply_author.'</a>'
                      . '<span class="pull-right">'.$datemade_r 
                       . '<b class="dropdown">
                         <small><span class="btn btn-xs btn-danger dropdown-toggle pull-right" data-toggle="dropdown"  >
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></span>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">'.$reply_delete_button
                      . '<li><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign" href="report.php?u='.$reply_author.'"> Report</a><li></ul></span>'
                      . '</small></b><br><legend>'.  html_entity_decode($reply_data1).'<br>'.$like_r.'|'.$unlike_r.'</legend></div>';


               } 
        echo '<textarea id="reply_textarea_'.$updateid.'"  class="status_reply_'.$updateid.' input-custom2" placeholder="comment\'s"></textarea>'
                            . '<button id="reply_butn_'.$updateid.'" attr="'.$updateid.'" type="b" class="btn btn-warning pull-right btn-sm reply_butn reply_'.$updateid.'">Reply</button></div></div>';

        }
}}                 
}?>
```

Answer (score -1):

For dynamically generated content use jquery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

[Why use jQuery on() instead of click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click)

[Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements?rq=1)

Comment: so, how do we normally hide a class if its loaded dynamically @chanchal118

Comment: at what event you want to hide a dynamically loaded element?