# Simple jQuery show/hide div alternating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hope someone can help me on this.

What I'm trying to do is when the `.video-play` is clicked, it will hide the `.video-link` div then show the `.video-container` div.

Then when the `.video-close` is clicked, it will hide the `.video-container` and show again the `.video-link` div.

Just to clarify, the div.wrap and everything under it including .video-close is only added via jquery when .video-play is clicked.

```
<div class="video-link">
  <a class="video-play" href="#">Play Video</a>
</div>

<div class="video-container">
  <!-- This part is added by a jquery script when .video-play is clicked -->
  <div class="wrap">
   <div class="content">
    <span class="video-close"></span>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- / end added part -->
</div>
```

Comment: You can find your answer easily by searching on web.

Comment: I have searched but I didn't find the exact function I'm looking for.

Comment: Certainly there is no exact answer for it. You need find your answer from multiple answer. However use [**this**](https://jsfiddle.net/94a3obrp/)

Comment: I have edited my OG post. The jquery (both answers of Mohammad and Mosh Feu can't seem to work if the .video-close is added by another jquery script after the page is loaded. Is there a solution to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that once you will read that code, you will understand..

```js
$(document).on('click', '.video-play,.video-close', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.video-link, .video-container').toggle();
});
```

```css
.video-container {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video-link">
  <a class="video-play" href="#">Play Video</a>
</div>

<div class="video-container">
  <a class="video-close" href="#">Close</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution is cleaner than mine - So have an upvote

Comment: @creativemix, Have you see my answer?

Comment: Thanks Mosh Feu! Will test it out.

Comment: I have edited my OG post. The jquery (both answers of Mohammad & Mosh Feu) can't seem to work if the .video-close is added by another jquery script after the page is loaded. Is there a solution to that?

Comment: @creativemix In this case you should use `on` instead of `click` see my updated code. Read the question and answers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10082031/863110

Comment: Thank you very much Mosh Feu! It's now working perfectly and learned something new too!