# onclick listener is not working with dynamic dom content

Tags: javascript, jquery

With jquery on several event i required to add elements but on that elements click event is not triggered. I tried to add the listener in the ready function also but it doesn't worked. Anyone please help.

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
       var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
       $('div.list').append('<div class="item-next">' + toAdd + '</div>')

   });
 
});

 $('.item-next').click(function(){
      alert()

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Find Listeners</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Find Listeners</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <button id="button">Click to Add</button>
  <br/><br/><br/>
      List
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (resolved). [learn more about delegate methods](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#button').click(function(){
 var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
 $('div.list').append('<div class="item-next">' + toAdd + '</div>')

 });
 $('div.list').on('click', '.item-next', function(){
  $(this).html($(this).html()+"<span style='color:red;'> clicked")
  alert('clicked on '+$(this).html());
   });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Find Listeners</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Find Listeners</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <button id="button">Click to Add</button>
  <br/><br/><br/>
      List
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Append event element Not work with normal click .so try with **[`on()`kindly  see the important of that](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

```
 $(document).on()
```

It helpfull to learn `on()` [**Why use jQuery on() instead of click()**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
       var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
       $('div.list').append('<div class="item-next">' + toAdd + '</div>')

   });
 
});

 $(document).on('click','.item-next',function(){
      alert('its work')

   });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Find Listeners</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Find Listeners</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <button id="button">Click to Add</button>
  <br/><br/><br/>
      List
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: see the hyperlink .i was posted with my answer

Comment: visit the link [Why use jQuery on() instead of click()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `quotation` on `'checkListItem'`

```
var toAdd = $("input[name='checkListItem']").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

well when you dynamically create an element use following structure as event listener:

```
$(document).on('click','.item-next',function(){
  alert();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This gonna work for you

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#button').click(function(){
       var toAdd = $('input[name=checkListItem]').val();
       $('div.list').append('<div class="item-next">' + toAdd + '</div>')

   });
 $(document).on("click",".item-next",function(){alert("myalert")})
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
     <title>Find Listeners</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <h2>Find Listeners</h2>
  <form name="checkListForm">
   <input type="text" name="checkListItem"/>
  </form>
  <button id="button">Click to Add</button>
  <br/><br/><br/>
      List
  <div class="list"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```