# Jquery click event for drop down list items

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a drop down list in an MVC application. When an item in the drop down list is selected (including the same one), I want to trigger a function. However, the first item in the list can't trigger the function and it should be disabled. I have some code below which works initially but after clicking a valid option and then clicking --Select-- again, it still fires the code. How do I fix this?

MVC Control

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlCountries", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Countries, "--Select--", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

jQuery to trigger the DDL click event

```
$('#ddlCountries option:not(:first)').click(function () {
            runCode()
});
```

jQuery to disable the first option

```
jQuery('#ddlCountries option:contains("--Select--")').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Comment: When you select for the first time your option and fire the event, do you not want it to fire again if the user clicks the select again?

Comment: personally instead of doing something fancy I would just put a check in the function.  if ($('ddlCountries').val() == "") return;  something like that

Comment: I never want select to fire anything. Ideally clicking it would do nothing (disabled). But I want any other item in the DLL when selected to always fire something.

Comment: I don't want to check the value because items get dynamically added so I think checking the value each time wouldn't be ideal

Answer (score 0):

Get the index of the selected option and check to see if it's greater than 0 on event fire. Indexes are 0 based.

```
$('#ddlcountries').on('change', function() {
  var index = $(this).find('option:selected').index();
  if (index > 0) {
    alert('yay');
    runCode();
  } else {
    alert('nay');
    return;
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the code to disable the first option because I couldn't get it to stay disabled after the first change. I modified the jQuery to trigger the event to:

```
jQuery('#ddlCountries').find('option:gt(0)').click(function () {
    runCode()
});
```

Then I added styling to the --Select-- box to make it gray. You can still click on it but it won't do anything. Not exactly what I was trying to do but close enough

Comment: Use `on` event instead. `$('#ddlCountries').on('click','option:gt(0)', function() { .. })`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click