# Click to html element loaded from PHP through jQuery AJAX won't work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a page that when clicking a button, the table with "id" attribute will appear which is loaded using jQuery AJAX with php. And in my JavaScript, putting a click event to table cell will not work.

Here's my full code. Hope you can help me.

dynamic_table.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
      table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
      }

      th, td {  
        padding: 15px;
      }

      td.filled {
        background-color: red;
      }
 
      td.unfilled:hover{
        background-color: blue;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button id="avail_seat_button" type="button">Show Available Seats</button>
    <div id="table_avail_seat">
      <!-- the table will appear here -->
 
    </div>
    <br />
    <input type="number" id="seat_no">

    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/handy_script.js"></script>
    <script src="js/available_seats.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

available_seats.js

```html
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#avail_seat_button").click(function(){
    $date_departure = "2017-10-22";
    $time_departure = "6:30 AM - 10:30 AM";
    $route = "Sagay-Cebu Via Tolido";

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "available_seats.php",
      data: {
        date_departure: $date_departure,
        time_departure: $time_departure,
        route: $route
      }
    }).done(function(result){
      $("#table_avail_seat").html(result);
    });
  });
});
```

code snippets form reservation.php class

```html
$cell = 0;
for ($row = 1; $row <= 9; $row++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($col = 1; $col <= 5; $col++) {
    $cell++;
    if (in_array($cell, $array_seats)) {
      //mark as not available
      echo "<td class='filled'>";
      echo $cell;
      echo "</td>";
    } else {
      //mark as available
      echo "<td class='unfilled'>";
      echo $cell;
      echo "</td>";
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

handy_script.js

```html
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $("td.unfilled").on("click", function() {
    alert("hello world");
  });
});
```

available_seats.php

```html
<?php
  include "php_library/SiteBasics.php";
  include "php_library/Reservation.php";

  $reservation = new Reservation;
  $reservation->available_seats();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to put this function

```
$("td.unfilled").on("click", function() {
    alert("hello world");
  });
```

inside the success of your ajax which replaces the html or you can simply replace this

```
$("td.unfilled").on("click", function() {
        alert("hello world");
      });
```

with this

```
 $(document).on('click', 'td.unfilled', function(){
  alert("hello world");
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

With dynamically generated elements, you have to use `jQuery.on("click", function() {});` instead of using `.click()`

See the link below for more details

[Why use jQuery on() instead of click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082031/why-use-jquery-on-instead-of-click)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried both .on() and .click() method. Still it won't work.

Comment: Could you post the HTML code after dynamic rendering? I want to make sure that the elements you are binding click event to are existed.

Comment: Try `$("#table_avail_seat").on('click','td',...`

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem on my own here. 
In my case, adding onclick=" " properties in my reservation.php code will work.
But still it's a question in my mind that why .click() or .on() will not work in my javascript.

Here's my revision of my reservation.php code:

```html
$cell = 0;
for ($row = 1; $row <= 9; $row++) {
  echo "<tr>";
  for ($col = 1; $col <= 5; $col++) {
    $cell++;
    if (in_array($cell, $array_seats)) {
      //mark as not available
      echo "<td class='filled'>";
      echo $cell;
      echo "</td>";
    } else {
      //mark as available
      echo "<td class='unfilled' onclick=\"alert('hello')\">";
      echo $cell;
      echo "</td>";
    }
  }
  echo "</tr>";
}
```

Comment: $(document).on('click', 'td.unfilled', function(){
  alert("hello world");
      });

Comment: try the above actually the elements created dynamically  so it will not work on document ready